# Boolean value of Tensor with more than one value is ambiguous

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, conv-neural-network, mobilenet

I have this class of NN:

```
class Block(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_planes, out_planes, stride=1):
        super(Block, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_planes, in_planes, kernel_size=3, stride=stride,
             padding=1, groups=in_planes, bias=False)
        self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(in_planes)
  
    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.conv1(x)
        out = self.bn1(out)
        out = nn.ReLU(out)
        return out
```

I create a model and pass it the random input, and it shows the error:

```
model = Block(3,3, 1)
x = torch.rand(64, 3, 100, 100)
model(x)
```

I received this error:
**RuntimeError: Boolean value of Tensor with more than one value is ambiguous**

Comment: Can you provide the whole error backtrace? It seems you haven't give the part of your code which is leading to that error.

Comment: The issue with the code is that I cannot use the nn.ReLU in the feedforward, I need to define it in the __init()__ or I should use the relu function from import torch.nn.functional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the `nn.ReLU()` in the `feedforward()`. I was printing it which is not possible in **ipynb** file.

```py
class Block(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, in_planes, out_planes, stride=1):
        super(Block, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_planes, in_planes, kernel_size=3, stride=stride,
             padding=1, groups=in_planes, bias=False)
        self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(in_planes)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()

    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.conv1(x)
        out = self.bn1(out)
        out = self.relu(out)
        return out
```

Comment: Please mark this answer as the correct one with a green tick, thank you!